# REACT - show loader spinner by setState inside .map()

Tags: reactjs

Got an array on objects from the server.
Want to display for the user a loader spinner when the request is lodaing.

```
const onDownland = (reportId: string) => {

    setDownloadLoadingState(() => true);

    backendAPIAxios.get(`/download/${reportId}`)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse<IDownloadResponse>) => { 

    })
    .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
    }).finally(() => {
      setDownloadLoadingState(() => false);  
    });
  };
```

The problem is I get multiple objects from the server, and I got one state that changes all of the objects UI.

```
<Button>
  {!props.downloadLoadingState ?
    <MSvg
      name='download'
      className={classes['svgContainerBlack']} 
      onClick={() => props.onDownload(history.id!)}
    /> :
  <Tooltip title={<h1 style={{ fontSize: '17px' }}>Loading</h1>} placement="left" arrow>
    <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
  </Tooltip>
 }
</Button>
```

[when loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVFu7.png)

[after loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpkl9.png)

How can I display the loader spinner for each object when I fire the request.

Added -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you move your loadingState into the Button component, you can have independent spinners for each object.

You can set the `onDownload` prop to an async function (i.e. a function returning a Promise), and manage the loading state inside the button component, instead of in its parent.

Something like this might work:

```js
// your button component

const [downloadLoadingState, setDownloadLoadingState] = useState(false);
...
<Button>
  {!downloadLoadingState ? // Now looking into local state, instead of prop
    <MSvg
      ...
      onClick={() => {
            setDownloadLoadingState(true)
            props.onDownload(history.id!).finally(() => setDownloadLoadingState(true))
            }
      }
    /> :
  <Tooltip ...>
    ...
  </Tooltip>
 }
</Button>


// in the parent component, keep only the fetching in onDownload and remove the loading state management
// then, return the axios promise so the .finally() can be used inside the button component
const onDownload = (reportId: string) => {
    return backendAPIAxios.get(`/download/${reportId}`)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse<IDownloadResponse>) => { 
    })
    .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
    });
  };
```

Comment: Please look at what Iv'e added

Comment: By looking at your latest screenshot, it looks like your `onDownload()` method returns a `void` value, but it is supposed to be returning a `Promise<void>`. Are you sure you've added the `return` command so it returns the axios Promise?